# Element wise array concatenation with numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, concatenation

```
a = np.array([3,4,5],[4,3,2])
b = np.array([4,7,2],[1,4,6])
```

I want to combine them in a way such that I will get,

`c = np.array([[3,4,5,4,7,2],[4,3,2,1,4,6]])`

How can I do that?

Comment: You have 2 (2,3) shaped arrays, and want a (2,6).  Have you tried `np.hstack`?  Read its docs.

Answer (score 1):

This has been achieved using
`np.hstack((a, b))`